# If word ends with Javascript

Tags: javascript, string, if-statement, cpu-word

I need some way to check if a word ends with certain letters. Basically, the user enters a string, which is split into words using:

`var res = spanish.split(" ");`

After this I need a way to check if any words in the string contain the letters 'est'. Right now I'm accomplishing that using

```
if (spanish.indexOf("est") !=-1) {

            }
```

After this, I need a way to check if the word containing 'est' ends with 'oy'. Any ideas?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith - has a ployfill for stupid browsers too

Comment: Regex? Or the string `.slice()` method to extract whatever the last two letters are so you can compare? What have you tried?

Comment: why not `spanish.search(/est.*oy$/) !== -1`

Comment: @nnnnnn I don't know much regex. So far I have just tried various javascript functions, but none seem to do the job.

Comment: @LeviVillarreal—I doubt it works perfectly, since it doesn't restrict *oy* to only be in the same word as *est*, only after it somewhere in the string, e.g. "feest and boy" returns true. `/est\w*oy(\W|$)/` would be better.

Comment: @RobG Ahhh.. I see now, thanks for pointing that out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I would use regex.

```
> /^.*est.*oy$/.test('fooestoy')
true
> /^.*est.*oy$/.test('fooesto')
false
>
```

Comment: That doesn't restrict "est" and "oy" to be in the same word, per "*…if the word containing 'est' ends with 'oy'*".